# Simple API to get current price of coin on stellar expert

Tags: stellar-website

Is there a simple API to grab coin details, such as current coin price?

I have not found a suitable solution for this as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to decide how to defined the *price* of a coin, should it be:

- The price of the most recent trade?
- The average price of the most recent *n* trades?
- A volume-weighted price of the most recent *X* units traded?
- The midpoint between the current bid/ask?

You can get the data you need from Horizon:

- Get the most recent *n* trades for a coin: [example](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=trades&endpoint=all&values=eyJiYXNlX2Fzc2V0Ijp7InR5cGUiOiJuYXRpdmUiLCJjb2RlIjoiIiwiaXNzdWVyIjoiIn0sImNvdW50ZXJfYXNzZXQiOnsidHlwZSI6ImNyZWRpdF9hbHBoYW51bTQiLCJjb2RlIjoiVVNEIiwiaXNzdWVyIjoiR0RVS01HVUdEWlFLNllIWUE1WjZBWTJHNFhEU1pQU1ozU1c1VU4zQVJWTU82UVNSRFdQNVlMRVgifSwib3JkZXIiOiJkZXNjIiwibGltaXQiOiIxIn0%3D&network=public)
- Get the orderbook data for a coin: [example](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=order_book&endpoint=details&values=eyJzZWxsaW5nX2Fzc2V0Ijp7InR5cGUiOiJuYXRpdmUiLCJjb2RlIjoiIiwiaXNzdWVyIjoiIn0sImJ1eWluZ19hc3NldCI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiY3JlZGl0X2FscGhhbnVtNCIsImNvZGUiOiJVU0QiLCJpc3N1ZXIiOiJHRFVLTUdVR0RaUUs2WUhZQTVaNkFZMkc0WERTWlBTWjNTVzVVTjNBUlZNTzZRU1JEV1A1WUxFWCJ9fQ%3D%3D&network=public)